# text scraping with beautiful soup and python is not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the text out of this html

```
  <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: aliceblue">
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="text-center" style="width: 10%">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/image/placeholder100.png" style="width: 100px">
        </td>

        <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a></td>
        <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/PartNumber/UH1H">UH1H</a></td>

        <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499">97499</a></td>
        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/cage/90/97499.jpg" title="CAGE 97499" alt="CAGE 97499"></a></td>
        <td nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle">

            <h4>&emsp;&emsp; MAMA,BEAR</h4>


            <p>
                <em>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Alternate References: <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a>, <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">000877637</a></em>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have to extract the following values separately

MAMA,BEAR

1520-00-087-7637

so i try to use this code

```
tablecontainer = page_soup1.find_all("tr")

    for container in tablecontainer:

            NSN = container.find("td", {"class": "text-center"}).a.text

            print(NSN)
```

when i run the code I get

> > > AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'

what am I doing wrong and how can I extract the values

Comment: which one `1520-00-087-7637` are you trying to scrap exactly ?

Comment: @coder the text not the one in the <a href> tag

Comment: Just before the line that causes the error, print `container`.  What is it, is it what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

data = '''
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: aliceblue">
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="text-center" style="width: 10%">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/image/placeholder100.png" style="width: 100px">
        </td>

        <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a></td>
        <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/PartNumber/UH1H">UH1H</a></td>

        <td class="text-center" nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499">97499</a></td>
        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 10%"><a href="/CAGE/97499"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="/Files/cage/90/97499.jpg" title="CAGE 97499" alt="CAGE 97499"></a></td>
        <td nowrap="" style="vertical-align: middle">

            <h4>&emsp;&emsp; MAMA,BEAR</h4>


            <p>
                <em>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Alternate References: <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">1520-00-087-7637</a>, <a href="/NSN/1520-00-087-7637">000877637</a></em>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
# extract the text from <h4> tag
for i in soup.find_all('h4'): print i.text.strip()
# extract the text from the link which contains the word 'NSN' in the href attribute
print soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='a' and 'NSN' in tag.attrs['href']).text
```

Also if you don't prefer to use a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), you can use [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) instead like so:

```
import re
re.compile(r'[NSN]*.')
print soup.find('a', attrs={'href':pt}).text
```

Comment: is like the print statement is an invalid syntax print i.text.strip()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @learner101 I had no such issue. Check for any indentation error. Try also to cp-paste my answer as is and check again.